# How to set the maximum length?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have this code :

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea',
    {
        height : 200,
        uiColor : '#bf3f23',
        toolbar :
        [
            ['Styles', 'Format', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link']
        ]
    });
```

How I can set the maximum length for the CKeditor and display a counter for it?

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles.

Comment: ok, sorry, I didn't mean that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is functionality not supported, [though it's scheduled for Milestone 3.x](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/397).

[This blog post](http://www.rodi.nu/blog/2010/06/ckeditor-maximum-length/) explains how you can hack the functionality in yourself, and [here's a plug-in](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1510662&group_id=75348&atid=737639).

<sub>**Source:** Google `ckeditor maximum length`</sub>